# JSON encoded dictionary in a dictionary not correctly deserialised using AFNetworking

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

in my PHP backend I am returning a JSON like so:

```
            $results_array=array();
            $stmt->bind_result($IdUser,$username);
            while($stmt->fetch()) {
                $row = array();
                $row["IdUser"]=$IdUser;
                $row["username"]=$username;
                $results_array[]=$row;

            }

            $stmt->close();
            echo json_encode(array("Response"=>"Login okay", "code"=>200, "results"=>$results_array));
```

My AFHTTPRequestOperation manager returns the responseObject (named results).

Now I want to get the user:

```
NSDictionary *user = (NSDictionary *)[results objectForKey:@"results"];
NSLog(@"%@",user);
[[API sharedInstance] setUser:user];

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self showAlertWithTitle:@"Logged in" andMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@",[user objectForKey:@"username"]]];
```

The app crashes with `"NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"`. I am checking the "user" object using NSLog, I get:

{
        IdUser = 49;
        username = kenny;
    }

which is still in JSON format. What am I doing wrong here? Why doesn't it deserialize to an NSDictionary within an NSDictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of items of type "User" and the "results" contains and array of dictionaries not simple dictionary. Try this code:

```
NSArray *userList = results[@"results"];
NSDictionary *user = userList.firstObject;
```